# how to add GUI to existing Qt project and how to disable qt shadow build

Tags: qt, user-interface, build, shadow

I am new to QT. And I want to use qt to add GUI to an existing project. I moved the original project to a Qt console application. Then I need to add GUI to it. Where should I start from? I took a look at some qt tutorial tutorials which start from creating new widget project. But there are not many about adding gui to an existing project.
I tried to add "QT += widgets gui" and "FORMS = myproject.ui" in the pro file. But I got error: No rule to make target 'myproject.ui', needed by 'ui_myproject.h'.

Also, can someone tell me how to disable shadow build in Qt creator 3.4.2 (based on Qt 5.5.0)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to disable Shadow build open "Projects" page from the left menu in QtCreator (right after "Debug") - there you can disable Shadow build option both for debug and release builds.
As for adding GUI I recommend you to create an empty Qt project (if you are using Qt 5.0 or greater you should add QT += widgets to your .pro file). There you can create a GUI you need - using forms or manualy as you wish. When your interface part will be complete you can add a non-gui functional part from existing source code. But that is a rather general recommendation as you see